# Linux email server, how to know a new email has arrived

Tags: python, linux, email

I am developing an email parsing application using python POP3 library on a linux server using Dovecot email server. I have parsed the emails to get the contents and the attachments etc. using POP3 library.

Now the issue is how to notify a user or actually the application that a new email has arrived? I guess there should be some notification system on email server itself which I am missing or something on linux which we can use to implement the same.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POP3 does not have push ability.  Like a regular ol' post office you need to actually go to check your e-mail.  IMAP does have functionality similar to (but not exactly the same as) mail pushing.  I'd suggest taking a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented another approach to use a cron to perform the task.